# Confidence Intervals with a known subset of data

Tags: confidence-interval

Lets imagine we have a data set with N data points, where the cost to "process" a data point is pretty high. Because of this, the processed N data points come in one by one. From this "streaming" data we produce a confidence interval describing the data.

As the data streams in, a user will see a confidence interval corresponding to some partial `(P)` set of the data. This confidence interval can occasionally appear significant over the `P/N` percentage of data processed, despite the fact that the "complete" (all N) data points would have a non-significant confidence interval.

Is there some way to modify the confidence interval calculation to account for the unknown (`(N - P) / N`) data, so that the confidence intervals are meaningfully wider when the data is incomplete?

Comment: The short answer is yes and this is called the finite population correction. When P = N then the confidence interval converges to a point, i.e. there's no uncertainty about the mean of this finite population. Beware repeated confidence intervals without a fixed sample size though.